# Rails naming convention misconception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to rails and since I've started learning i had a lingering question..
in tutorials when they generate a model (User for example) from the cmd
with the command --> "rails generate model User etc...."
the class name Starts with capital and the file name is in small letters (user.rb)
and when creating relations they use the small letters one.
i've looked online but it must've been a dumb question or is there something that i'm missing.
Thanks!

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct. So an instance of the class `Company` might be `@company` and its employees are  instances of the class `Employee`, and because a company `has_many :employees` we can represent them by `@company.employees`. Only the class names are ever capitalized.

Comment: IIRC you can pass the model name as camel case or snake case to the generator and it will convert it as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not just a Rails convention, but a Ruby one.

- Class and module names are `CamelCase`, for example `MyAwesomeClass` ([reference](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#camelcase-classes)).
- Filenames are `snake_case.rb`, for example `my_awesome_class.rb` ([reference](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#snake-case-files)).
- variable names are lowercase `snake_case` ([reference](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#snake-case-symbols-methods-vars)).
- method names are lowercase `snake_case` ([reference](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#snake-case-symbols-methods-vars)).
- Constants (other than modules or classes) are `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` ([reference](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#screaming-snake-case-for-constants)).

Comment: In addition, constants must start with an uppercase letter and variables must not start with one.  (they would become a constant otherwise)

Comment: So the database (sqlite) will store it as i enter it in the cmd or in small case?
cause i've looked in the schema and it is stored as small letters
So no matter how i enter it itll always be in small letters?

Comment: @AbdullahTaqiedin I apologize, I missed that part of your question was about active record naming conventions.  I have not used active record for a long time, but as near as I can recall, active record uses `lowercase_snake_case` for table and column names.

Comment: @AbdullahTaqiedin table names in snake case (plural)

Answer (score 3):

Just as note to naming convention

Rails use convention over configuration, but sometimes you need to customize names

For example

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym "RESTful"
end
```

If don't use such config, you need to use `r_e_s_tful.rb` with `RESTful` class

But using it, you can define `RESTful` in `restful.rb` without problems